# Shell enviar mensagem de erro

Tags: shell, bash

Tenho uma tarefa cron rodando que chama um shell script. Esse arquivo sh faz um backup do banco de dados e salva em uma pasta no servidor. Até aí está funcionando.

Sei que no momento de gerar o backup e/ou salvar pode acontecer um erro. Gostaria de enviar esse erro para um e-mail ou gerar algum log de erro, alguma coisa assim. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Segue o script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# bkpDBData.sh
#
# gera um dump da base de dados, somente dos dados para um zip no servidor
#

# echo 'Iniciando backup SGI!';

local_save_backup=/local/salvar/backups
ano=`date +%Y`
path_complete=$local_save_backup'/'$ano

# verifica se existe a pasta do local_save_backup+ano
# se nao existe, entao cria a pasta
if [ ! -d $path_complete ]; then
    # echo "criar pasta";
    mkdir $path_complete
    # echo "pasta criada";
fi

mysqldump -h localhost -u user -psenha -x -e -t nome_da_base | gzip > $path_complete/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`_mysql.gz;

# echo 'Fim do backup SGI!';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quaisquer mensagens de erro serão enviadas para o `stderr`, que é o output padrão de erros do shell. O `strerr` é identificado pelo número `2` quando se quer fazer alguma ação com esses erros.

Assim, suponhamos que sua cron faz uma chamada do tipo:

```
bkpDBData.sh
```

Vamos alterar essa chamada para gravar os erros em um log:

```
bkpDBData.sh 2>/var/log/bkdbdata.log
```

Em seguida, você pode programar uma cron para pegar as mensagens do log de 1 em 1 minuto e enviá-las para um email:

```
mail -s "bkpdbdata" seu@email.com < /var/log/bkpdata.log
```

Comment: Muito bom, algo que não sabia e vou estudar sobre. Já fiz o teste e gerou um erro (no caso coloquei uma senha errada para poder gerar). Eu não tinha a ideia se era no cron ou no shell que eu tinha que fazer essa verificação, mas agora já me abriu mais a mente para isso.